# Facing issues while grouping data for bar chart in dc js using crossfilter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

```
`d3.json('dc_test_case.json', function(error, data) {
            var data = data;

            var ndx = crossfilter(data);

            homeDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){
                return d.Inning;
            });


            nameDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){
                if(d.Inning === "England batting"){
                return d.Name;
                }
            });

             runName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {

                if(d.Inning === "England batting") {
                return Number(d.Runs);
                }


            });





            var England_batting = dc.barChart("#England_batting");
            England_batting.width(700)
                .height(480)
                .gap(30)
                .yAxisLabel(".", 50)
                .xAxisLabel("U", 50)
                .dimension(nameDim)
                .group(runName)
                .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(nameDim))
                .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
                .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 200]))
                .elasticY(true)
                .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
                .renderTitle(true)
                .brushOn(true);



            dc.renderAll();

        });
```

The bar chart of England batting are not correct, there data is wrong. I think I shouldn't use reduceSum to group data. I don't know what should I use... Anyone solve this issue...

json of this code is given below...

```js
[
    {
        "Name": "ME Trescothick",
        "Out": "c Hussey b Symonds",
        "Runs": "41",
        "Minutes": "55",
        "Balls": "37",
        "4s": "5",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "110.81",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d3a"
  },
    {
        "Name": "KP Pietersen",
        "Out": "c Hayden b Clarke",
        "Runs": "34",
        "Minutes": "19",
        "Balls": "18",
        "4s": "3",
        "6s": "1",
        "SR": "188.88",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d3b"
  },
    {
        "Name": "A Flintoff",
        "Out": "c Symonds b Kasprowicz",
        "Runs": "6",
        "Minutes": "9",
        "Balls": "5",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "120.00",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d3c"
  },
    {
        "Name": "GO Jones†",
        "Out": "c Kasprowicz b McGrath",
        "Runs": "19",
        "Minutes": "17",
        "Balls": "14",
        "4s": "4",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "135.71",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d3d"
  },
    {
        "Name": "MP Vaughan*",
        "Out": "c Ponting b Symonds",
        "Runs": "",
        "Minutes": "2",
        "Balls": "1",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "0.00",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d3e"
  },
    {
        "Name": "PD Collingwood",
        "Out": "c Ponting b McGrath",
        "Runs": "46",
        "Minutes": "28",
        "Balls": "26",
        "4s": "5",
        "6s": "2",
        "SR": "176.92",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d3f"
  },
    {
        "Name": "AJ Strauss",
        "Out": "b Gillespie",
        "Runs": "18",
        "Minutes": "15",
        "Balls": "16",
        "4s": "1",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "112.50",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d40"
  },
    {
        "Name": "VS Solanki",
        "Out": "c Hussey b McGrath",
        "Runs": "9",
        "Minutes": "5",
        "Balls": "5",
        "4s": "1",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "180.00",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d41"
  },
    {
        "Name": "J Lewis",
        "Out": "not out",
        "Runs": "",
        "Minutes": "1",
        "Balls": "",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "-",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d42"
  },
    {
        "Name": "Extras",
        "Out": "(lb 1, w 3, nb 2)",
        "Runs": "6",
        "Minutes": "",
        "Balls": "",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d43"
  },
    {
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d44",
        "Total": "Total",
        "Total-D": "(8 wickets; 20 overs; 79 mins)",
        "R": "179",
        "RPO": "(8.95 runs per over)"
  },
    {
        "Name": "GD McGrath",
        "Runs": "31",
        "4s": "4",
        "6s": "",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia bowling",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d45",
        "Over": "4",
        "Maiden": "",
        "Wickets": "3",
        "Economy": "7.75",
        "0s": "10"
  },
    {
        "Name": "B Lee",
        "Runs": "31",
        "4s": "4",
        "6s": "",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia bowling",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d46",
        "Over": "3",
        "Maiden": "",
        "Wickets": "",
        "Economy": "10.33",
        "0s": "6"
  },
    {
        "Name": "MS Kasprowicz",
        "Runs": "28",
        "4s": "3",
        "6s": "",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia bowling",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d47",
        "Over": "3",
        "Maiden": "",
        "Wickets": "1",
        "Economy": "9.33",
        "0s": "2"
  },
    {
        "Name": "JN Gillespie",
        "Runs": "49",
        "4s": "6",
        "6s": "2",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia bowling",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d48",
        "Over": "4",
        "Maiden": "",
        "Wickets": "1",
        "Economy": "12.25",
        "0s": "5"
  },
    {
        "Name": "A Symonds",
        "Runs": "14",
        "4s": "1",
        "6s": "",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia bowling",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d49",
        "Over": "3",
        "Maiden": "",
        "Wickets": "2",
        "Economy": "4.66",
        "0s": "7"
  },
    {
        "Name": "MJ Clarke",
        "Runs": "25",
        "4s": "1",
        "6s": "1",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia bowling",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d4a",
        "Over": "3",
        "Maiden": "",
        "Wickets": "1",
        "Economy": "8.33",
        "0s": "4"
  },
    {
        "Name": "AC Gilchrist†",
        "Out": "c Pietersen b Gough",
        "Runs": "15",
        "Minutes": "11",
        "Balls": "14",
        "4s": "3",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "107.14",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d4b"
  },
    {
        "Name": "ML Hayden",
        "Out": "c Pietersen b Gough",
        "Runs": "6",
        "Minutes": "12",
        "Balls": "4",
        "4s": "1",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "150.00",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d4c"
  },
    {
        "Name": "A Symonds",
        "Out": "c Pietersen b Lewis",
        "Runs": "",
        "Minutes": "5",
        "Balls": "2",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "0.00",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d4d"
  },
    {
        "Name": "MEK Hussey",
        "Out": "c Flintoff b Gough",
        "Runs": "1",
        "Minutes": "6",
        "Balls": "6",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "16.66",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d4e"
  },
    {
        "Name": "RT Ponting*",
        "Out": "c Solanki b Lewis",
        "Runs": "",
        "Minutes": "6",
        "Balls": "3",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "0.00",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d4f"
  },
    {
        "Name": "DR Martyn",
        "Out": "c Trescothick b Lewis",
        "Runs": "4",
        "Minutes": "6",
        "Balls": "4",
        "4s": "1",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "100.00",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d50"
  },
    {
        "Name": "B Lee",
        "Out": "c Harmison b Collingwood",
        "Runs": "15",
        "Minutes": "29",
        "Balls": "20",
        "4s": "1",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "75.00",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d51"
  },
    {
        "Name": "MS Kasprowicz",
        "Out": "not out",
        "Runs": "3",
        "Minutes": "16",
        "Balls": "5",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "60.00",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d52"
  },
    {
        "Name": "GD McGrath",
        "Out": "b Harmison",
        "Runs": "5",
        "Minutes": "9",
        "Balls": "12",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "41.66",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d53"
  },
    {
        "Name": "Extras",
        "Out": "(b 1, lb 2, w 1, nb 2)",
        "Runs": "6",
        "Minutes": "",
        "Balls": "",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d54"
  },
    {
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia-batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d55",
        "Total": "Total",
        "Total-D": "(all out; 14.3 overs; 64 mins)",
        "R": "79",
        "RPO": "(5.44 runs per over)"
  },
    {
        "Name": "D Gough",
        "Runs": "16",
        "4s": "3",
        "6s": "",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England bowling",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d56",
        "Over": "3",
        "Maiden": "",
        "Wickets": "3",
        "Economy": "5.33",
        "0s": "13"
  },
    {
        "Name": "J Lewis",
        "Runs": "24",
        "4s": "3",
        "6s": "",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England bowling",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d57",
        "Over": "4",
        "Maiden": "",
        "Wickets": "4",
        "Economy": "6.00",
        "0s": "14"
  },
    {
        "Name": "SJ Harmison",
        "Runs": "13",
        "4s": "2",
        "6s": "",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England bowling",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d58",
        "Over": "2.3",
        "Maiden": "",
        "Wickets": "1",
        "Economy": "5.20",
        "0s": "9"
  },
    {
        "Name": "MJ Clarke",
        "Out": "c †Jones b Lewis",
        "Runs": "",
        "Minutes": "1",
        "Balls": "1",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "0.00",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d59"
  },
    {
        "Name": "JN Gillespie",
        "Out": "c Trescothick b Collingwood",
        "Runs": "24",
        "Minutes": "18",
        "Balls": "18",
        "4s": "4",
        "6s": "",
        "SR": "133.33",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "Australia batting",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d5a"
  },
    {
        "Name": "A Flintoff",
        "Runs": "15",
        "4s": "2",
        "6s": "",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England bowling",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d5b",
        "Over": "3",
        "Maiden": "",
        "Wickets": "",
        "Economy": "5.00",
        "0s": "10"
  },
    {
        "Name": "PD Collingwood",
        "Runs": "8",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "",
        "Home": "England",
        "Away": "Australia",
        "Date": "Jun 13, 2005",
        "Ground": "Southampton",
        "Series": "Australia tour of England and Scotland",
        "Match_No": "Only T20I",
        "Winning_info": "England won by 100 runs",
        "Inning": "England bowling",
        "id": "569aa1f87e655d7e6af61d75",
        "Over": "2",
        "Maiden": "",
        "Wickets": "2",
        "Economy": "4.00",
        "0s": "6"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the following, I think:

```
runName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  if(d.Inning === "England batting") {
    return Number(d.Runs);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
```

The problem is that you return undefined in the event that Australia is batting, and `15 + undefined` evaluates to `NaN`.

Also: Please create a working example in the future. I was able to just eyeball this one, but there is no way for me to check if my solution actually works. You are far far more likely to get help if you create a working example.